# Elasticsearch Query: Boosting specific field

Tags: elasticsearch, field, boosting

I am using Elasticsearch 2.4.3 and want to boost specific fields in my query. Is this possible? I only see how I can boost an index.

Greetings!

**UPDATE**

Mapping:

```
"firstName":{"type":"string",
     "analyzer":"customNGram"
},
"lastName":{
     "type":"string",
     "analyzer":"customNGram"
},
"note":{
     "type":"string",
     "analyzer":"customNGram"
}
```

Query (Java API):

```
    QueryBuilder qb = new BoolQueryBuilder()
        .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("_all", term)
                .analyzer("atsCustomSearchAnalyzer")
                .operator(Operator.AND));

    SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = elasticsearchClient.prepareSearch("persons", "activities").setTypes("person", "activity")
            .setQuery(qb)
            .addHighlightedField("*").setHighlighterRequireFieldMatch(false)
            .setHighlighterOrder("score")
            .setHighlighterFragmentSize(150)
            .setHighlighterForceSource(true)
            .setSize(100)
            .addIndexBoost("persons", 200)
            .setFrom(offset); 

    return searchRequestBuilder.execute().get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split up your match-query to match individual fields, eg using a multi match query (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html), you can boost the field you like. So something like:

```
QueryBuilder qb = new BoolQueryBuilder()
    .must(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(term, "firstName^3",
    "lastName^3", "note")
            .analyzer("atsCustomSearchAnalyzer")
            .operator(Operator.AND));
```

should boost firstName and lastName 3 times relative to the note field.